# How to check if you have the asymptotic solution of some equation?

Tags: co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

Suppose I have an analytic function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and I have the asymptotic expansion of some $x_0$ up to a few terms in terms of $\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \to 0$ which I believe is such that $f(x_0) = 0$. How can I prove that $$f(x_0) = 0$$

Some context - In my case, I am trying to compute the asymptotic expansion of the solution to some saddle point equation of form $f(x) = 0$, in order to apply the saddle point method from Asymptotic Analysis/Analytic combinatorics/analytic number theory. However, actually computing the solution to this equation seems difficult. Instead, I want to 'guess' the solution to the equation, and prove that my guess is correct. Is this possible?

Comment: It could be but this kind of problem can easily become impossible, so more details are needed. For example, let $x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i2^{-i}$ where $a_i = 0$ in general but $a_i = 1$ if $i$ is the Gödel code of a proof of 0 = 1 from ZFC (say). Then I do have a way to approximate $x$ as much as I want by decoding $i$ and checking whether this is a valid proof. My guess is that $x = 0$ but I can't possibly prove that.

Comment: Suppose I know in addition that there exists some $x_0$ with $f(x_0) = 0$?

Comment: Simulposted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616695/how-to-check-if-you-have-the-asymptotic-solution-of-some-equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\bar x_0$ be your approximation of $x_0$. Find a small $\delta$ such that $f(\bar x_0)$ and $f(\bar x_0+\delta)$ have opposite sign. Then you know $x_0$ to an accuracy of $|\delta|$ (assuming $f$ is continuous and monotonic as it usually is in the saddle-point method).

More generally, show that Newton's method converges or find a contraction mapping.